# Dapper is accessing all properties of my class when doing a select from the database even when it should not

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I am using jquery datatables to display a table of data.  The table is only displaying 3 columns from my SqlFunction.

I use dapper like this:

```
 IQueryable<MyClass> data = null;
 // Execute my sql statement and map the resultant fields into MyClass properties
 data = sqlCon.Query<MyClass>("SELECT field1, field2, field3, FROM dbo.MySqlFunction()", selector.Parameters).AsQueryable();
```

In the above code "selector" is a Dapper.SqlBuilder.

MyClass has a property:

```
public List<Address> MailingAddresses
{
    get
    {
        if (_MailingAddresses == null)
        {
            _MailingAddresses = new List<Address>();
        }
        if (_MailingAddresses.Count == 0)
        {
            Address temp = new Address();
            _MailingAddresses.Add(temp);
        }
        return _MailingAddresses;
    }
    set
    {
        _MailingAddresses = value;
    }
}
```

Even though I only select 3 fields from my sql function and tell dapper to map it to an IQueryable of MyClass the MailingAddresses get accessor is executed.   I have code that reads US states from either cache or db in the Address class which is how I even found out this was happening.

I do not access the MailingAddresses property anywhere on my first page (the page that just lists a table with 3 fields from MyClass.)

I have narrowed it down to Dapper as being the culprit.  I made a copy of my MyClass and removed the MailingAddresses property and it no longer tried to run the code to get the list of states from the database.

I have seen various references to prevent Dapper from accessing properties on Insert/Update but they do not work on select.  They were [Computed] from Dapper.Contrib and [IgnoreProperty(true)] from Dapper.Rainbow.

How can I keep Dapper from accessing unreferenced properties when doing a SQL Select?

[Stack Trace of Break Point on getter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57VBm.png)

Edit
[Full Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faKgh.png)

Now I'm thinking it may not be dapper at all (that's a relief) but the serialization into json.  Is there a way for the serialization to ignore properties?

Here is how I return the data to my View from the Controller:

```
   return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsFiltered, recordsTotal = recordsFiltered, data = recs });
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the getter, then run to it. Then share the stack trace when it gets hit.

Comment: Are you using the Watch Window or the Immediate Window to view those objects? If so, the IDE is likely calling the getter without you realising.

Comment: `I have code that reads US states from either cache or db in the Address class which is how I even found out this was happening.` Show us that code.

Comment: 1. Added stack trace of getter.  It just shows External Code.
2. Nothing in watch window.
3. It just checks cache and if not in cache reads db.  But the point is, that code should not even ben called.

Comment: Go into Visual Studio Options and turn off "Debugging / Just My Code" then you can see the full stack trace

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface.  It looks like it is not Dapper but is actually Json serialization causing all properties to be accessed.

Comment: Yes, json serializing will do that.

Comment: Use the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not caused by Dapper, it is caused by `JsonSerializer` accessing the property.

If you add the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to your property then it will not be accessed by `JsonSerializer`

Comment: I found it has to be the one in  [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore].   Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you just copied what people already said in the comments...

Comment: @JHBonarius Correct, others did mention it, but it was kinda obvious once we got the stack trace. And answers are supposed to be in an answer post, [not left in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294792/14868997)

Comment: You're misreading that qa. The op asks if when he answered the question in the comments, he himself should post an answer. It doesn't say you should copy other people's answers. I.e. imho you should have stimulated @mxmissile to post an answer.